# Formatting FASTA files

Tags: bash, awk, format, fasta

I have been looking for a way to format FASTA files using Bash commands from

```
gi|723654225|ref|XP_010314935.1| PREDICTED: F-box/kelch-repeat protein At1g55270-like [Solanum lycopersicum]
MDQTIERSSNAHRGFRVQPPLVDSVSCYCNVDSGLKTVAGARKFVPGSKLCIQSDISSHAHKSKNSRRER
SRVQPPLLPSLPDDLAIACLVRVPRVELSKLRLVCKRWYRLLAGNFFYSQRKSLGMAEEWVYVVKRDRDG
RITWHAFDPTYQLWQPLPPVPGDYGEALGFGCAVLSGCHLYLFGGKDPIKGSMRRVIFYNARTNRWHRAP
```

to

```
F-box/kelch-repeat protein At1g55270-like
MDQTIERSSNAHRGFRVQPPLVDSVSCYCNVDSGLKTVAGARKFVPGSKLCIQSDISSHAHKSKNSRRER
SRVQPPLLPSLPDDLAIACLVRVPRVELSKLRLVCKRWYRLLAGNFFYSQRKSLGMAEEWVYVVKRDRDG
RITWHAFDPTYQLWQPLPPVPGDYGEALGFGCAVLSGCHLYLFGGKDPIKGSMRRVIFYNARTNRWHRAP
```

How would I do that in Bash?

Comment: A few issues: is this really your FASTA file? The label line usually starts with `>`, which helps immensely with parsing. 2. You have to be more precise: how exactly is that line to be modified? Delete the first and last two whitespace separated words? Probably not, but what exactly? 3. If you show your efforts, people will be much more helpful. At the moment, it looks like you just want somebody else to do your work for you, instead of helping you with *your* work - what did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '/F-box/ {$0=$3" "$4" "$5} {print}' file
```

With this file:

```
gi|723654225|ref|XP_010314935.1| PREDICTED: F-box/kelch-repeat protein At1g55270-like [Solanum lycopersicum]
MDQTIERSSNAHRGFRVQPPLVDSVSCYCNVDSGLKTVAGARKFVPGSKLCIQSDISSHAHKSKNSRRER
SRVQPPLLPSLPDDLAIACLVRVPRVELSKLRLVCKRWYRLLAGNFFYSQRKSLGMAEEWVYVVKRDRDG
RITWHAFDPTYQLWQPLPPVPGDYGEALGFGCAVLSGCHLYLFGGKDPIKGSMRRVIFYNARTNRWHRAP
```

Output:

```
F-box/kelch-repeat protein At1g55270-like
MDQTIERSSNAHRGFRVQPPLVDSVSCYCNVDSGLKTVAGARKFVPGSKLCIQSDISSHAHKSKNSRRER
SRVQPPLLPSLPDDLAIACLVRVPRVELSKLRLVCKRWYRLLAGNFFYSQRKSLGMAEEWVYVVKRDRDG
RITWHAFDPTYQLWQPLPPVPGDYGEALGFGCAVLSGCHLYLFGGKDPIKGSMRRVIFYNARTNRWHRAP
```